# Better way to pull Subsite & SUB-Subsite Navigation?

Tags: 2013, navigation, global-navigation

Here's the scenario:

We have a web app with roughly 325 sub-sites. About half of these have more than 1 sub-site. So let's say 500 sub-sites, and sub-sites OF sub-sites. What would be the best approach for diplaying links for all of these THAT A USER HAS ACCESS TO? So I for example would see ALL of these links, while the average user may only see 4-5.

The way it is currently set up is a custom .wsp that creates a top nav with the links (Home - SUBSITES - SUB/SUBSITES) and all the sites are in those dropdowns. The problem is that because of this solution, the site load times are horrendous. Looking for a better alternative. Was thinking a page or web part that would display the links as mentioned above. Looking for advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the search web parts and use the following query:

```
ContentClass:STS_Web
```

This will return all of the webs (sites) that a user has permissions to. To limit it to a subset of sites, add a search for a URL.

```
ContentClass:STS_Web path:https://yourServerUrl/sites/yourSite
```